# Error to execute simple CRUD in java with oracle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, crud, ojdbc, oracle

guys.
The code below don't work.Accuses error.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XEPDB1","hr","hr");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE student(rno number, name varchar(20),branch varchar2 (20))");
        st.close();
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=53331:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.3.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Eclipse\Intellij\CRUDPuro\out\production\CRUDPuro Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Driver ojdbc11.jar that installed in this paths

[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: shouldn't it be part of external libraries? can you drag and add it to external library section ?

Comment: Tip: Learn to use Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `.jar` as external library.
Check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-module-library) guide
Hope this helps.